# Buster lists external hard drive twice, same name

Tags: linux, debian, mount, raspberry-pi, hard-disk

I have a pi running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) armv7l with an external hd attached via usb.

For some reason I have that hd listed twice in /media/pi. One of them has a "1" appended to the name and also has a "file" field when I view its properties. Please see the screenshot.

What is this "second" hard drive? Is it a symlink?

Some other data that may be relevant. I am running syncthing in a docker container and have  added the hd as a resource for the container with `- /media/pi/14TB External/Syncthing:/Syncthing` under volumes in docker-compose.yml.

Any time I restart the pi I run into this issue where I need to switch the volume between `14TB External` and `14TB External1` via the compose file and restart docker in order for syncthing to find the drive.

How can I prevent this "second" drive from appearing? [image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all the folder in `/media` is not the drive, it is a [mount point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)), folder where contents of the drive (filesystem on it) can be accessed. When the driver isn't mounted, it's just an empty folder, there isn't anything special about it. So you don't have the drive twice, you have one unused folder `/media/pi/14TB External` and one folder `/media/pi/14TB External1` used as mount point for your drive.

Why you have the folder twice? Mounting in GUI is done by [UDisks](http://storaged.org/) which also automatically creates the mount point in `/media/<user>`. If the mount point already exists, it is not reused but UDisks creates a new one by appending number to it. UDisks should remove the folder after you unmount the device (or shutdown the machine), but this was broken in older versions of UDisks and it sometimes doesn't work so you can end up with multiple "old mount points" in `/media`.

To fix this simply remove the `/media/pi/14TB External` folder and next time UDisks will create it when mounting the drive and mount it there. (Note: Make sure you didn't accidentally saved anything to `/media/pi/14TB External` first, that would mean the data was not saved on the external drive so deleting the folder would mean you lose the data.)